# Does Vuetify have something similar to WPF GroupBox

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need a simple component that organizes sets of controls into a group that has a header.
Vuetify has components named that start with Group, but they are essentially different components.
Perhaps it is called something else.
Or it can be simply implemented. I would be glad if someone points out an example of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) for this.